# How to debug this stdc++ crash on osx 10.5

Tags: c++, macos, dylib

I have a .dylib I built for integrating as an Adobe AIR native library.  The code runs great on osx 10.6, 10.7, and 10.8, but I've gotten reports that it's crashing on 10.5.  I can't seem to find instructions (that actually work) on how to get a 10.5 VM working under Mountain Lion so I can diagnose it.  Has anyone come across a crash like this before?

```
Process:         AudioStretch [247]
Path:            /Applications/Speedshifter.app/Contents/Resources/assets/native/audioStretcher/AudioStretch
Identifier:      AudioStretch
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  Speedshifter [240]

Interval Since Last Report:          771 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           4
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  0 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   4

Date/Time:       2012-08-15 15:56:24.047 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.5.8 (9L31a)
Report Version:  6
Anonymous UUID:  19E6C7D0-BED3-47EF-BD79-4C93716A6EEA

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: __ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_i
  Referenced from: /Applications/Speedshifter.app/Contents/Resources/assets/native/audioStretcher/AudioStretch
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
```

Comment: Well, it appears that something inside the "ostream" class doesn't exist on the 10.5 version. Running "c++filt" on the symbol name will give a more readable version of it, but I doubt it will help a lot... EDIT: are you actually telling X-Code that your minimum MacOS version is 10.5? If you aren't, then maybe just adding this will help. Or maybe not :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
> c++filt __ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_i
std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)
```

Reformatting for easy reading:

```
std::ostream& std::__ostream_insert(std::ostream&, char const*, int)
```

Basically it is saying this function is not available in the standard runtime in 10.5

You may have to provide an alternative version of the dll for 10.5. Have you tried statically linking against the standard libraries?